# how to create subsets of pandas dataframe based on a boolean array value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset, slice

I am working on a pandas dataframe where one column (`bullish`) consist of boolean values and the second one (`split`) is also boolean based and it is True whenever the first column value is different than the one before it.
I did this:

```py
df['split'] = df['bullish'] != df['bullish'].shift(-1)
```

Now i would like to slice the pandas dataframe in smaller subset at each point where the `split` value is True so that it creates subsets where all `df['bullish']` values are either only **True** or only **False**.

[image: the dataframe I have]

Thank you in advance for your insights !

Comment: Provide some sample data as text. Indicate what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow. Please be so kind as to review [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) before asking further questions on Pandas

As for your specific question, let's start with a simple example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'bullish' : [True, True, True, True, False, False, True]})
```

Then we can split as such (note I think you got the `shift(-1)` slightly wrong here)

```
df['split'] = df['bullish'] != df['bullish'].shift() 
df
```

this produces

```
    bullish split
0   True    True
1   True    False
2   True    False
3   True    False
4   False   True
5   False   False
6   True    True
```

To achieve what you want you can use a combination of `groupby` and `cumsum` applied to the `'split'` column, like so:

```
for id, g in df.groupby(df['split'].cumsum()):
    print(f'group_id = {id}')
    print(g)
```

This will print three dataframes with the same `'bullish'` value inside each:

```
group_id = 1
   bullish  split
0     True   True
1     True  False
2     True  False
3     True  False
group_id = 2
   bullish  split
4    False   True
5    False  False
group_id = 3
   bullish  split
6     True   True
```

Since you did not specify what output you actually wanted (another good practice on SO) I will leave it at that